# Querying Firebase Database with Android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to log in using firebase database, wherein i already have some data stored.

[image: This is my Database tree!]

So i need to post some kind of query for searching a particular node which is matching the entered credentials as Input, and View its Reference key for confirmation.
Here is my code, which just doesn't seem to be successful, as it always going for the exception case and giving out the error toast.
I would be more than obliged to get a solution to my issue.

```
public class LogInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference Rootref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference mwritefarmref = Rootref.child("WRITE FARM");
    DatabaseReference muserprofilestab = mwritefarmref.child("USER PROFILES");

    EditText mobinputtext;
    EditText passwordinputtext;
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);

        mobinputtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobinputtext);
        passwordinputtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passinputtext);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        Button submitbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitbutton);
        submitbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    DatabaseReference muserid = (DatabaseReference) muserprofilestab.orderByChild("Mobile number").equalTo(mobinputtext.getText().toString());
                    tv.setText(muserid.getKey());
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "ERROR!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: I would start with first changing your database structure. Also, please avoid having spaces in `keys`. Use camelCaseLetters.

Comment: Ohh! Thanks for the Advises! :D

Comment: But now is there a way to perform the required on this DataBase itself?!

Comment: I didn't understand the question. Could you re frame it? I believe, I can provide solution to your question, provided u make it clear...

Comment: Its like, in from the above database, when i get a mobile number inputed by any user, i want to derive and display out the the corresponding parent key node.
E.g: When the user inputs the mobile number "9705050504", the app should display the parent key, i.e., "31201000004"

Comment: *When i used Query instead of typecasting it to DatabaseReference, it is unfortunately giving out "USER PROFILES" which is not the desired output to me.
                            Query loginquery = muserprofilestab.orderByChild("Mobile number").equalTo(mobinputtext.getText().toString());
                    tv.setText(loginquery.getRef().getKey());

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast a Query to a DatabaseReference. Instead of:

```
DatabaseReference muserid = (DatabaseReference) muserprofilestab.orderByChild("Mobile number").equalTo(mobinputtext.getText().toString());
```

do this:

```
Query myquery = muserprofilestab.orderByChild("Mobile number").equalTo(mobinputtext.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding! :)
But I've already tried that......
Once I added such query, and then output the KEY of the obtained query, it is returning "USER PROFILES", while what we want is "3120100004"
Soooo?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is not a relational database. It's a NOSql db. Things work a little different here. Speed is the ultimate goal not the space as they say!
If you want to retrieve the parent key based on the mobile no input, then create another node 'MobileNoDetails' under root. Under the 'MobileNoDetails' node store the user mobile number as the key, and under it store the user parent key "31201000004". That's how you can retrieve the user parent key upon entering the Mobile number.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot! I definitely got your point. I can definitely get through with that process. :) But then as you may know that it is turning out be relatively very complex method of doing it. Hence, ultimately is it just impossible to get it done the way I am trying to do it?